# C++ Using External .lib file - error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, saprfc

I am a newbie in C++ and getting the below error while compiling an old C++ application. On reading various posts here, my understanding is that the function call might be missing some parameters. Now, the function is a part of static library. How do I identify the missing parameters? Or is (enough) required information there in the error message below?

> rfcclass.lib(crfcglob.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "class std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl std::operator<<(class
>   std::basic_ostream > &,char const *)"
>   (??6std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@PBD@Z)
>   referenced in function "public: __thiscall
>   CRfcTrace::~CRfcTrace(void)" (??1CRfcTrace@@QAE@XZ)

Thanks.

Comment: Show the code of destructor of `class CRfcTrace`.

Comment: Here it is:           CRfcTrace::~CRfcTrace() { #if defined(_WIN32) || defined(SAPonNT) // cleanup all threadTraceItems and close all trace files while( m_pTraceList ) { CriticalSection.Lock(); threadTraceItem *pTemp = m_pTraceList; m_pTraceList = m_pTraceList->next; //delete pTemp->pOfTrace; delete pTemp; CriticalSection.Unlock(); } #else ofTrace.close(); #endif #if defined(_WIN32) || defined(SAPonNT) CriticalSection.Lock(); #endif m_nTraceCreated--; #if defined(_WIN32) || defined(SAPonNT) CriticalSection.Unlock(); #endif }